# jQuery getting text-shadow variabile

Tags: jquery, css

I want to get 4 variables when I click on a span that have the CSS3 text-shadow propriety. So for a css propriety of `text-shadow: -4px 11px 8px rgb(30, 43, 2);`, my code should be:

```
$("#element").click(function () {
var text-shadow = $("#element").css("text-shadow")
});
```

Would it be possible to get it split like:

```
var y = "-4px";
var x = "11px";
var blur = "8px";
color = "rgb(30, 43, 2)";
```

I need to somehow split the first variable to get this data.

Thanx

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should use regular expression to split the result of jQuery css into the variables you are looking for.

```
var result = $('#element').css('text-shadow').match(/(-?\d+px)|(rgb\(.+\))/g)
// result => ['rgb(30, 43, 2)', '-4px', '11px', '8px']
var color = result[0],
    y = result[1],
    x = result[2],
    blur = result[3];
```

This will return an array splitting the `text-shadow` string value into numbers with pixels and rgb values. It can help you in this particular case, but you'll probably need to work on it some more to get it working for all the possible cases of `text-shadow`

**NOTE:** The `rgb(...)` value is the first match in the array because, that is the way Firefox, Chrome, Safari and Opera return it, independently of how you assign it. IE might do it differently.

Comment: That's a pretty good cross browser solution, works in Firefox, Chrome and Safari, didn't get a chance to test in IE, thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Obvious way would be:

```
var properties = $('#element').css('text-shadow').split(" ");

var y = properties[0];
var x = properties[1];
var blur = properties[3];
var color = properties[4] + " " + properties[5] + " " + properties[6];
```

Comment: The property order is backwards

Answer (score 1):

Since I don't think there is a way to extract out each value from the CSS individually, the easiest way to do it would be to do some string manipulation. And since the value returned is in this order: color, y, x, blur, you'd end up with this script:

```
 var p = $('#element').css('text-shadow').split(' ');
 var color = p[0]+p[1]+p[2];
 var y = p[3];
 var x = p[4];
 var blur = p[5];
```