# Get shadow style with jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

I have a div to which [some CSS shadow](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-shadow.asp) will be applied. I need to get the following shadow elements with jQuery:

- `h-shadow`, `v-shadow`, `blur` and `spread` in pixels
- The `color` *of the shadow*, in some string, doesn't matter how
- `inset`, if it is applied in the `box-shadow` property.

How to do it? Are there some specific CSS properties, like `border-top-right-radius` to get the top right border radius instead of working with `border-radius`?

---

So, example code:

```
<div id="the_div" style="box-shadow:10px 10px 5px 2px #f00 inset;">...</div>
```

Now some JavaScript...

```
$(function(){
    $('#the_div').someFunction(); // returns the h-shadow, for example
});
```

Comment: what do you mean with "I need to get....with jQuery"?

Comment: I want to get the value, just like with `$('selector').height()`. But then not the height, but these properties.

Comment: The problem is I don't have any yet, but I added some example code with a div for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want, is this kind of thing:

[jQuery getting text-shadow variabile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2683260/jquery-getting-text-shadow-variabile)

Basically, the solutions is just to use some regex to split the text shadow into `color`, `y`, `x`, and `blur`.

Comment: That's what I needed! I'll mark my question as a duplicate. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery("#divID").css("color");
```

That will get the color - jQuery will get the css property you ask for: [jQuery CSS](http://api.jquery.com/css/)

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear, what I want is the color of that is applied to CSS's `box-shadow` property.

Answer (score 0):

```
alert($('.myElementClass').css('box-shadow));
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
div.xxx {
    position: relative;
    background-color: #abc;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    float: left;
    margin: 5px;
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888888;
}
</style>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<p><button id="go">Run »</button></p>
<div class="xxx"></div>
<script>
    $( "#go" ).click(function(){
        alert($('.xxx').css('box-shadow'));
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I need to get the values separated, so one variable with the `h-shadow`, one with the `v-shadow`, etc.

Comment: As I said in my answer, this is a simple string parsing exercise. You can split the returned string with a space character to get an array, then based off the rules of CSS you'll know which array element corresponds to which property.

Comment: @FrankB it isn't as easy as that. Look at the **NOTE** [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2683393/1544337): different browsers may act differently.

Comment: @CamilStaps the link you just showed here,  looks like the right answer. (Sorry Bernie haven't seen you posting that.) I could not do it any better. did you already try (the NOTE) and check what IE, Opera and Safari are returning?

Comment: Welcome to web design. In your function test for which browser the user is using, then base your parsing of the string on that result. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10257810/javascript-check-browser) for how to test for the user agent. Then use the code in the answer you showed me and adjust it to fit the situation.

Comment: @caramba I made [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FY6Ap/1/) to test, but I don't have IE9. IE-low gives an `undefined`. FF, GC, Opera and Safari all return the same: `color h-shadow v-shadow blur spread`. Can someone else test IE9+?

Comment: @CamilStaps, everyone helping you here for nothing is not rude! everything he mentioned with his comment is that we're not going to do your work. your fiddle has no regex from all the answers. if you put the parts together from all those answers you got here, you have it. you have it all on the plate, now you just have to eat and if you don't like vegetables always tell your self that they're good for you.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use:

```
$("#divID").css("box-shadow");
```

Then parse the returned string for the properties you want. Since the string may vary I'm not going to write out a function. But you should be able to take it from here.

EDIT:
Because different browsers behave differently you can check for the browser using the top answer from [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10257810/javascript-check-browser)

Also the answer you linked to in a previous comment on another answer, answers your question. It can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2683393/1544337)

Comment: "Then parse..." yes, but how... That's exactly the problem.