# what is the best way to find out actual box-shadow values?

Tags: javascript, css

I need to find the actual box-shadow element values of a css style rule that is written by the server. More specifically I need to know if the element has a visible shadow or not. 
which means, there may be a case where the shadow rule is not "none" but not displayed because the rgba value has 0 opacity, or the blur is 0 and the spread is negative.

any ideas?

Comment: With jQuery: `$(element).css('box-shadow');`

Comment: this is not enough. I need to determine whether any box-shadow is rendered/displayed, in all the different edge cases. the fact that there's a box shadow property doesn't mean anything if the opacity is 0 for example.

Comment: You'll get back a string with the box-shadow properties. You can parse it and find out if it is visible according to your rules. I don't think there is another way to determine the visibility of a box-shadow

Comment: It is also pretty similar to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2683260/jquery-getting-text-shadow-variabile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using both [`.css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/) and [`.match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) methods you can easily get `text-shadow` value of the element :

```
var text_shadow = $('div').css('text-shadow').match(/(-?\d+px)|(rgb\(.+\))|(rgba\(.+\))/g);
```

---

Here is a [working JSFiddle with what you need](https://jsfiddle.net/7n129cay/). But you must know that :

- If the alpha value in `rgba` is set to 0, the browser sees it as if you didn't put any color (`undefined`).
- You [can't set the blur to a negative value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length) :

> For some properties, using negative lengths is a syntax error, but for some properties, negative lengths are allowed.